# disable copy the description in my magento website frontend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

Anyone knows how to disable copy function from the description in my magento website frontend?

is there any javascript can help please

Comment: nothing can stop any one copying anything you put on the web.

Comment: there's no point, and that's why right click disabling died a long time ago. Disabling javascript in browser with one click will defeat anything you install, and that's just one of many methods your content can be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the mouse contextmenu and keydown event, prevent the context menu to show and prevent the default action if user press ctrl+c.

```
el.attachEvent('contextmenu', function(event){
   if (event.preventDefault) {
          event.preventDefault();
   } else {
          event.returnValue = false;
          // Some keys events require setting the keyCode to -1 to be prevented
          try {
              // all ctrl + X and F1 -> F12
              if (event.ctrlKey || event.keyCode > 111 && event.keyCode < 124) {
                  event.keyCode = -1;
              }
          } catch (e) {}
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this one is help you

http://www.morshed-alam.com/2009/05/disable-text-selection-in-your-web-page.html

Hope it helps.

Thanks,